# need to acces values individually outside a for loop from a array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop

I have a php for loop with a calculating. now i want to put each value from the calculating into a array and acces them individually outside the for loop.

This is not working, im getting all kind of errors regardless from what im trying

Here is my code

```
$week=1; // Begin week
    $eind_week1 = 4; // Einde week eerste berekening
    $eind_week2 = 9; // Einde week tweede berekening

    $groei_dynamiek = array();

    for($week; $week <= $eind_week1; $week++) // Dit is een berekening tot week 4, de weken daarna is een andere berekening. Zie hieronder
    {

        $groei_dynamiek1    = -0.0195 * pow($week, 3) + 0.1092 * pow($week, 2) - 0.073*$week + 0.0059;
        $groei_dynamiek1    = sprintf("%.1f%%", $groei_dynamiek1 * 100);

        $groei_dynamiek["week"][] = $groei_dynamiek1;

        @$totaal += $groei_dynamiek;
    }

echo $groei_dynamiek["week"][0];
echo $groei_dynamiek["week"][1];
echo $groei_dynamiek["week"][2];
echo $groei_dynamiek1["week"][3];
```

Comment: In every single iteration of your loop you do this: `$groei_dynamiek1 = array();` Take a few minutes to think about why that is a problem.

Comment: Hi, i placed it outside my loop now, but still its not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `$groei_dynamiek1 = array();` must be placed before the for loop. Otherwise, every iteration of the loop will set the array empty, ignoring what value was added to it in the previous iteration. There must be another statement `$totaal = 0;` before the loop. Always remember that suppressing error with `@` is not really a good idea. Lastly, you shouldn’t perform the calculation on the array itself; rather, you need a temporary variable (let’s call it `$temp`). Correcting these errors, your code becomes:

```
$week = 1; // Begin week
$eind_week1 = 4; // Einde week eerste berekening
$eind_week2 = 9; // Einde week tweede berekening
$totaal = 0;
$groei_dynamiek1 = array();
for($week; $week <= $eind_week1; $week++){
// Dit is een berekening tot week 4, de weken daarna is een andere berekening. Zie hieronder
        $temp = -0.0195 * pow($week, 3) + 0.1092 * pow($week, 2) - 0.073*$week + 0.0059;
        $temp = sprintf("%.1f%%", $temp * 100);
        $groei_dynamiek1["week"][] = $temp;
        $totaal += $temp;
}
unset($temp);
echo $groei_dynamiek1["week"][1];
```

Comment: Thank god, thank you for the explaination. This works perfecly. Sorry but im new to php.

Comment: And also thanks for the $totaal solution. Dindt know you have to assign a empty or 0 value to it.

Comment: @Julez, I don't speak Dutch to suggest better names, but you might want to consider renaming your variables as well.  It is generally, a bad practice to give variables the same name and just append a different number to each (`@eind_week1` vs `$eind_week2` and `$groei_dynamiek1` vs `$groei_dynamiek`)  Among other reasons, it makes it very easy to introduce a bug via simple typo hitting numbers next to each other on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

$groei_dynamiek1 is set to an array but  $groei_dynamiek1['week'] is not.

```
   $groei_dynamiek1["week"] = array();
```

is needed.